# How to clone parent element with all the sub elements in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have the following code to Add new Paragraph when I click on a button. I'm cloning the "sub" div and append it to the "main" div. But with cloning the "sub" div, it is copying only the content of "sub" div which is "inner" div instead copying with the "sub" div. I need to have several "sub" divs after cloning it several times. But now only the first paragraph has "sub" parent div and all the other cloning divs has "inner" parent div. How can I do this?

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(".main").append($(".sub:last").clone().html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>
        New Paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Add new</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add specific arguments if you want a deep copy (see the [`.clone()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/clone) for more):

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
 $(".main").append($(".sub:last").clone(true, true));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="sub">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>
        New Paragraph
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Add new</button>
```

## EDIT

Above, I removed `.html()` so the `<div class="sub>` will be added to the `main` div, not just the `inner` div.

Comment: But still new paragraphs has not a "sub" div

Comment: That's because you're appending the `.html()` of the clone. Removing it will clone the entire `sub` div and append it to `main`. I'll edit my answer.